# grails rendering plugin incompatible return type issue

Tags: java, grails, grails-plugin

I am working on a grails 3 (grails version 3.2.3, java version 1.8) project where it needs to convert a gsp into a pdf. I tried to use the rendering plugin provided by grails.
I imported the plugin using:
    `compile 'org.grails.plugins:rendering:2.0.3'`
in my build.gradle file

and in my controller
i used:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = pdfRenderingService.render(template: "/templates/pdf_PI", model: [proformaInvoice: proformaInvoice])
```

to render the pdf. The service is injected using `def pdfRenderingService`

however i m getting this error

```
grails-app/controllers/chsam/re/ProformaInvoiceController.groovy: -1: The return type of java.lang.Object getPdfRenderingService() in chsam.re.ProformaInvoiceController is incompatible with grails.plugins.rendering.pdf.PdfRenderingService in grails.plugins.rendering.RenderingTrait. At [-1:-1]  @ line -1, column -1.
```

I spent hours trying to get this plugin to work but it just won't work. Please help.

Comment: plz add dependency this dependencie, dependencies {
        runtime 'org.springframework:spring-test:4.1.6.RELEASE'
}

Comment: please add this compile "org.grails.plugins:rendering:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT" instead of adding this  compile 'org.grails.plugins:rendering:2.0.3'

Answer (score 0):

Solved this issue by explicitly using types when declaring the service. Instead of `def pdfRenderingService` use `PdfRenderingService pdfRenderingService`.

Works on grails 3.2.11, using `org.grails.plugins:rendering:2.0.3`